# Problems loading i18next.js with require.js

Tags: requirejs

I'm pretty new to require.js and having problems loading i18next.js.

main.js

```
require(["lib/jquery", "lib/i18next", "config.i18next", "constants"],    
  function(util) {
     console.log("loaded javascript files");
});
```

and config.i18next.js

```
var option = {resGetPath: '../translations/__lng__.json' };
i18n.init(option, function(t) { 
    console.log("Language initialization successfull");
});
```

I always get the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: i18n is not defined            config.i18next.js:2
```

I know who to use i18next, and everything works fine when loading the javascript files traditionally.

---

EDIT:

Meanwhile I got it working with shim like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        'lib/i18next' : ['lib/jquery'],
    }
});

require(["lib/i18next"], function(i18n) {
    var options = {
        resGetPath: 'translations/__lng__.json',
        preload: ['de', 'en'] 
    };
    i18n.init(options, function(t) { 
    });
});
```

and I can translate in other files with `$.t("key");` , but when now I can't change the language programatically with `i18n.setLng()` because the variable can't be found `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: i18n`.

Comment: i18next comes now with a extra build for [amd i18next](http://i18next.com). this should solve your issues. take the version with jquery! there you can $.i18n.setLng(...)

Comment: should probably be an answer instead of a comment? Could you please add it so I can accept it?

Comment: done. answer could be accepted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

--- i18next comes now with amd build ---

this should solve all issues using i18next with amd. you can grab it at http://i18next.com